# Fresh titanium hello world won't run on any emulator

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

Im completely new to titanium appcelerator and I did google this but only found outdated problems. I build a titanium alloy project I've installed xcode and connected the android sdk.

when I try to run on the the android emulator I get this error:

```
[ERROR] :  Emulator process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 1s 663ms
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1`
```

when i try to run on the iPhone emulator I get this error

```
[ERROR] :  An error occurred running the iOS Simulator
[ERROR] :  [DEBUG] using retina iphone retina ios 7
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 1m 25s 11ms
```

I really don't have an idea where this comes from, and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the Iphone simulator and you would be good to go

```
iOS Simulator->Reset Content and Settings...
```

Thanks